# How can I use data from a synchronized data extension in Marketing Cloud Intelligence dashboard

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, dashboard, datorama

I have an issue whereby I am trying to see how many customers opportunity stage changed to Closed won (placed an order), within 3 days of opening certain emails.

We don't have Marketing Cloud connected to GA4, and customers can also place an order over the phone as well as web anyway - So getting some rough insights via marketing cloud intelligence could really help us understand if emails are helping to convert to orders.

I'm just not sure how i can show opportunity stage data from within Intelligence? this data is in a synchronised DE since we are connected to Salesforce via marketing cloud connect

Any help will be appreciated